# A rational integral with exponential denominator

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, laplace-transform

Prove that:
$$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{4}}\text{d}x}{\left( \beta +{{\text{e}}^{x}} \right)\left( 1-{{\text{e}}^{-x}} \right)}}=\frac{\left( {{\pi }^{2}}+{{\ln }^{2}}\beta  \right)}{15\left( \beta +1 \right)}\left( 7{{\pi }^{2}}+3{{\ln }^{2}}\beta  \right)\ln \beta,\ \ \beta>0$$

Comment: I bet it is given $\,\beta > 0\,$ ...?

Comment: Really, if you read through the solution to your other question, you should be able to do this one in principle.

Comment: @rlgordonma : THx! I am just reading your solution